# php creating a file from string with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, string, file, codeigniter

```
$data = base64_encode('Hello World');

            // echo '<pre>';
            // print_r(strlen(base64_decode($data)));
            // echo '</pre>';
            // exit;
            //strlen(base64_decode($data));
            //filepath
            ob_clean();
            //header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache");  
            header("Content-type: text/plain"); 
            header("Content-length: ".strlen(base64_decode($data)).""); 
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=qwe.Lot"); 
            exit(base64_decode($data));
```

I want to create a file from a string in PHP in my code above I have it it my controller. It only prints the string but not downloading the file.

1. How to create a text file from string in Code Igniter?

UPDATE
This is the out put in the browsers debug

[image]

Comment: Try using echo instead of exit? (Not sure if this will work)

Comment: Also `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` the case of the headers.

Comment: i used `echo (base64_decode($data));` same result just putting the string in browser not downloading @ErtySeidohl

Comment: @DhavalPurohit I dont understand what you mean

Comment: the `t` and `l` in the header should be in capital @guradio

Comment: man you are using an `ajax` ?

Comment: yes I am. Also changed the Capital letters still now working @DhavalPurohit

Comment: In ajax it will not work as you expected just use
`window.location = the same url you are using for ajax`

Answer (score 0):

This way may help.

```
<?php
$file = 'file.txt';
$data = 'this is your string to write';
file_put_contents($file, $data);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For file save

```
$data = base64_encode('Hello World');
$filename = "text.txt";
file_put_contents(filename, data);
```

For File View

```
$filename = "text.txt";
$content = json_decode(file_get_contents($filename));
```

This file will save on your project root folder. You can put file path before the file name.